# C++ invalid conversion from ‘const type* const’ to ‘type*’

Tags: c++, qt

I have a very silly question (I think). Its been long time not coding in C++, but I can't figure out this problem.
I have this class:

```
#include <QList>
class Node {
private:
    QList<Node*> _adjacent;
public:
    Node();
    bool isConnectedTo(Node* n) const;
};
```

and this implementation for `isConnectedTo()`:

```
bool Node::isConnectedTo(Node* n) const{
    return _adjacent.contains(n) && n->_adjacent.contains(this);
}
```

and I get the following error in the `return` line:

```
Node.cpp: In member function ‘const bool Node::isConnectedTo(Node*) const’:
Node.cpp:25:60: error: invalid conversion from ‘const Node* const’ to ‘Node*’ [-fpermissive]
In file included from /usr/include/qt5/QtCore/QList:1:0,
                 from Node.hpp:5,
                 from Node.cpp:1:
/usr/include/qt5/QtCore/qlist.h:913:27: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘bool QList<T>::contains(const T&) const [with T = Node*]’ [-fpermissive]
```

I think that, since the method is constant, then `this` is of type `const Node* const` here.
By reading th Qt doc, I see that `QList::contains` has the type `bool QList::contains(const T & value) const` so it should be ok, right? I mean, it takes a `const Node*`, and a `const Node* const`is a special case of that, so...
By removing the `const` at the end of the siganture, it compiles...

Thanks!

Comment: You're passing a pointer where it expects a reference.

Comment: @OMGtechy, A reference to a pointer that is.

Comment: `const T &` when `T` is `Node *` means `Node * const &`, not `const Node *&`.

Comment: @chris thanks, missed that

Comment: `this` is a pointer to constant, so it can't be accepted as `(Node *n)` argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problem is here:

```
n->_adjacent.contains(this)
```

Since contains assumes that it will get `Node* const` and `this` is type of `const Node*`. Adding `const` is not a problem but removing is a problem. So try `const_cast` like this:

```
n->_adjacent.contains(const_cast<Node* const>(this))
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I thought that `this` had type `const Node* const`, that was my initial mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your "isConnectedTo" function "this pointer" is a const Node * const pointer which means that "this" cant be used to change the contents of the Node object that it refers to.

In your call "n->_adjacent.contains(this)" you are passing "this" pointer to a function which has constant reference parameter (const T& ref where T is Node*). const T& ref where T is Node* means ref is Node* const& i.e a constant reference to a pointer. The constant here refers to the pointer and means that the reference cant be used to alter the pointer. But this does not mean that the reference cant be used to change the object (Node) that the pointer points to. So nothing can stop us from doing something like (*ref).call_to_non_const_function_in_Node.

But "this" pointer in your case points to a constant Node objject. That is why this code doesn't compile. It would have compiled if the parameter were a constant Node* const& i.e constant reference to a pointer to a constant

When you remove const modifier from your member function "this" is just a regular Node* const  pointer which is why it compiles.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to change `Node`s through the `_adjacent` list, change its declaration to

```
QList<const Node*> _adjacent;
```

Otherwise you probably have to resort to `const_cast`, or remove the `const` qualifier from your function.